# How to translate wordpress timestamp in different languages

Tags: wordpress, timestamp, translation

I have a site in Wordpress with the widget WPML Multilingual CMS and the site is translated in 3 languages. All the site is translated except the timestamps, they are in english. 
Is there a way to translate the timestamps according to the selected language ?

Comment: Some update, i used .mo file for IT and RO language and the translation is working only for the time 
"Posted: marzo 10, 2015" - IT
"Posted: martie 10, 2015" - RO
The word "Posted" remains the same.

Comment: I assume that the theme you're using works with WPML. There's a good change you can find the word "posted" in your theme's strings and translate it from there.